# Dart CORS doesn't work

Tags: spring, dart

Hello I want to make an request to my Spring server. Now I'm getting an error because of an restricted CORS option.
So I added an filter because the annotations doensn't work:

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public CORSFilter() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }}
```

Now my problem is, that the cors filter won't work on an dart request.
On an normal browser request the header is set but not in the dart http request.

Is there any solution which could fix this problem?

Update 23.09.2016:
Here is the http://pastebin.com/9KNfx7Jd
The problem is that the filter is not affected to this http call.
Only when I access the file via URL in the browser it works.

Here with ajax:

`Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8090
Request URL:http://localhost:8090/time/time/login
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:114
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 23 Sep 2016 12:57:55 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:WildFly/10
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=ZIkzLq-iALC6CDx7r6LhPz_8PiD05Q9ufod6GluZ.ccn6dc2; path=/time
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8090
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.104 (Dart) Safari/537.36`

And here without:

`Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8090
Request URL:http://localhost:8090/time/time/login
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:5
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Fri, 23 Sep 2016 13:10:36 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:WildFly/10
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=nQFjGB2m7ovHVT9VUnhtCJSXZvEZV4WWH0YCrgFk.ccn6dc2; path=/time
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic c2tvYmxlcjpTMW1vbjUyNzli
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=oHJ4GvQ8pFNv8HSujI49NRXQxoVSVMM580sSrvJW.ccn6dc2
Host:localhost:8090
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.104 (Dart) Safari/537.36`

Edit 26.09.2016:

Okay I changed now my SecurityConfig to this:

`@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }`
    now the filter is beeing called but I get now a new error: `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401`

Headers: 
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:114
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 26 Sep 2016 12:30:39 GMT`

Comment: What do you mean by a "dart request" ? You mean that in a request fired from dart code, the headers are not present in the response to the request?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: Its not really possible to see what might be wrong if there is no information presented here. Some code of your dart application and a dump of an example HTTP request that is failing would be a start.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/9KNfx7Jd) here is the link to the http call function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your filter is not applied for `OPTIONS` requests.
A comment to this blog post indicates that `OPTIONS` requests need to be enabled explicitly:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

> One "gotcha" that I found when working with CORS with Spring MVC (when using a Filter or HandlerInterceptor) and Spring Security is that you need to explicitly permit all OPTIONS requests to properly handle the pre-flight. The W3C specification for CORS says that pre-flight requests should not send credentials, however I have found that some browsers do send the credentials, and others don't. So if you don't permitAll OPTIONS you get a 403 if the browser is not sending the credentials.
>
> Will pre-flights requests be something that will need to be specifically configured when using Spring Security or will the pre-flight be handled before the filter chain?

See also

- [Disable Spring Security for OPTIONS Http Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696592/disable-spring-security-for-options-http-method)
- [Enable CORS for OPTIONS request using Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733501/enable-cors-for-options-request-using-spring-framework)
- [How to handle HTTP OPTIONS with Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521690/how-to-handle-http-options-with-spring-mvc)
- [How to handle HTTP OPTIONS requests in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331042/how-to-handle-http-options-requests-in-spring-boot)
- [Spring and HTTP Options request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096195/spring-and-http-options-request)

Comment: alright I did the following in the SecurityConfig class: 
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();`

but it didn't fixed the error 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8090/time/time/jsontime. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`

Comment: And this fixed your issue?

Comment: sorry, had problems with the new line ^^.
Nope it didn't :(. I edited the comment above.

Comment: I don't know much about Spring, but I'm sure this needs to be fixed on the server not on the Dart side (I stumbled upon your question because of the Dart tag).

Comment: so when I disable the Security it works fine. But I have to use the security because of the user cridentials. Maybe there is another workaround that could fix this problem.

Comment: yes it is not called within an dart request. In an normal request by the browser it is called.

Comment: If you load the URL directly from the browser URL bar, then it's not a CORS situation. CORS is when the page is loaded from a different URL (different server or different port) than the request you make from your code. This means that no `OPTIONS` preflight request is made at all when you insert the URL to the browsers URL bar and a `GET` is made instead. You need to configure your server to properly respond to `OPTIONS` requests.

Comment: So I did the following: I changed the RequestMapping to method = OPTIONS but still same error (401)

Comment: Can you exclude `OPTIONS` requests from security? For an `OPTIONS` request there should only be an empty response with the CORS headers set, and it is therefore not security relevant

Comment: I did this already: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();`

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481850/how-to-send-a-http-options-request-from-the-command-line/14489636 to see if you can reproduce outside Dart.

Comment: So what I did, I used the extension **postman** which outputs the following:

`<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>Access is denied</body>
</html>` so that means, I think that the security doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I worked around with disabling the web security for chromium.
Thanks to all of you for helping me :)